# Select a substring from a string in C#

Tags: c#

how to select a substring from a string in the most rational in C#, from whitespace to symbol '#'? 
for example:

```
"Jungle #welcome to the jungle"
```

Result:`#welcome`

Comment: does `string.Substring` not do what you want?

Comment: How do you want to handle these strings? a) `xx #welcome #welcome` b) `xx # welcome #welcome xx`, c) `xx ##welcome xx`

Comment: I found solution:

s.IndexOf("#");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string originalString = "Jungle #welcome to the Juncle";
string subString = originalString.Substring(originalString.IndexOf("#"));
subString = subString.Substring(0, subString.IndexOf(" "));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Match m = Regex.Match("Jungle #welcome to the jungle", @"\s(#\w+?)\s");
Console.WriteLine(m.Captures[0].Value);
// #welcome
```